# Support optional columns in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, database-versioning

I have database with schema controlled by separate department. I would like to make some columns optional with default values. I think it would be best if I could set attribute `[OtherProductMinimumVersion(OtherProductVersion.1_27)]`, where `OtherProductVersion` is enum versioning other product.
My application upon start would read schema version from database and pass it to DbContext constructor.

Is there way of doing this in Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core without creating such framework myself?